# Como fazer personagem pular enquanto está andando?

Tags: javascript, jogos

Eu estou criando um jogo em JavaScript. Esse é o meu primeiro contato com a linguagem e também o desenvolvimento de jogos.

Indo direto à pergunta, consigo andar e pular no jogo, porém quando estou andando e pulo, o jogo não executa nada, para de andar e também não pula (o jogo não congela, se soltar as teclas e apertar novamente ele faz as funções de andar e pular normalmente).

**Essas funções verificam a tecla pressionada e executam a função:**

```
function jump(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 38){
            cube.pula();
        }
    }


function walk(){
        if(event.keyCode == 39){
            cube.right();
        }
        if(event.keyCode == 37){
            cube.left();
        }
    }
```

**Essas são as funções (pular, direita, esquerda). As funções ficam dentro de um objeto chamado cubo:**

```
pula: function(event){
            if(this.jps < 2){
                this.jps++;
                this.v = -this.fp;
            }else if(this.y == 250){
                this.jps = 0;
                this.jps++;
                this.v = -this.fp;
            }
        },

        right: function(){
                if(this.x <= width-64){
                    this.x += this.force;
                }
        },


        left: function(){
            if(this.x >= 15){
                this.x += -this.force;
            }
        },
```

**Coloquei o código no CodePen como foi pedido.Também coloquei um comentário no html explicando as variáveis.**

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/toniotti/pen/MMJpeY

Comment: Precisamos de um pouco mais de informação pra te ajudar, por exemplo: Onde são chamadas as funções `jump` e `walk`? O que significam as variáveis `jps`, `v`, `fp`, `force`, e onde elas estão sendo usadas? Dá pra chutar o que elas fazem, mas é bem mais fácil se você explicar, e as chances de conseguirmos te ajudar aumentam x)

Answer (score 1):

Como é seu primeiro contato com a linguagem, te aconselho dar uma estudada sobre Debugger, ou como a maioria dos programadores JS que faz gambiarra (como eu haha), ao menos utilize o console.log para saber o que está acontecendo.

Por exemplo, dentro de cada função, coloque um console.log com a informação da ação:

```
console.log('walk')
console.log('right')
console.log('left')
console.log('jump')
```

E também coloque um `console.log('event.keyCode', event.keyCode)`. Com isso, provavelmente você verá que as duas teclas foram pressionadas, assim como nesse exemplo: https://franciscoprado.com.br/teclas-pressionadas-com-javascript-jquery/

O que você pode fazer é um if para walk + jump, e em caso negativo, ou seja, ele não pulou, somente andou, você executa somente o event.keyCode de jump também está ativo, e em caso positivo, chamar a função.

Ainda tem pouco código para te ajudar. O melhor seria se você colocasse isso em algum site como o codepen e disponibilizar para te ajudarmos.